# Trouble starting dgraph with TLS

Tags: graph-databases, tls1.2, tls1.1, dgraph

I'm trying to start a dgraph server with TLS enabled, my server config file is defined as following:

```
# Folder in which to store exports.
export: export

# Fraction of dirty posting lists to commit every few seconds.
gentlecommit: 0.33

# RAFT ID that this server will use to join RAFT groups.
idx: 1

# Port to run server on. (default 8080)
port: 8080

# GRPC port to run server on. (default 9080)
grpc_port: 9080

# Port used by worker for internal communication.
workerport: 12345

# Estimated memory the process can take. Actual usage would be slightly more
memory_mb: 4096

# The ratio of queries to trace.
trace: 0.33

# Directory to store posting lists.
p: p

# Directory to store raft write-ahead logs.
w: w

# Debug mode for testing.
debugmode: true

# Address of dgraphzero
peer: localhost:8888

# Use TLS connections with clients.
tls.on: true

# CA Certs file path.
#tls.ca_certs: /Users/pauloferreira/Workspace/RagnarTech/Node/base_backend_njs/certificates/development/development-server-root-CA.pem

# Include System CA into CA Certs.
tls.use_system_ca: true

# Certificate file path.
tls.cert: /Users/pauloferreira/Workspace/RagnarTech/Node/base_backend_njs/certificates/development/development-server-root-CA.pem

# Certificate key file path.
tls.cert_key: /Users/pauloferreira/Workspace/RagnarTech/Node/base_backend_njs/certificates/development/development-server-root-CA.key

# Certificate key passphrase.
#tls.cert_key_passphrase string

# Enable TLS client authentication
#tls.client_auth string

# TLS max version. (default "TLS12")
#tls.max_version string

# TLS min version. (default "TLS11")
#tls.min_version string
```

As soon as I start dgraphzero and dgraph, if the configuration tls.on is equal true, this output is shown:

```
Setting up listener at: localhost:8888
Setting up listener at: localhost:8889
2017/10/19 16:09:36 main.go:163: Loading configuration from file: development.conf
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["export" = export]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["grpc_port" = 9080]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["workerport" = 12345]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["p" = p]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["tls.ca_certs" = /Users/pauloferreira/Workspace/RagnarTech/Node/base_backend_njs/certificates/development/development-server-root-CA.pem]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["memory_mb" = 4096]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["peer" = localhost:8888]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["gentlecommit" = 0.33]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["idx" = 1]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["port" = 8080]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["trace" = 0.33]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["tls.on" = true]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["tls.cert" = /Users/pauloferreira/Workspace/RagnarTech/Node/base_backend_njs/certificates/development/development-server-root-CA.pem]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["w" = w]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["debugmode" = true]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["tls.use_system_ca" = true]
2017/10/19 16:09:36 init.go:74: Picked flag from config: ["tls.cert_key" = /Users/pauloferreira/Workspace/RagnarTech/Node/base_backend_njs/certificates/development/development-server-root-CA.key]

Dgraph version   : v0.8.3
Commit SHA-1     : 40175d0
Commit timestamp : 2017-10-18 15:55:02 +1100
Branch           : HEAD

2017/10/19 16:09:36 node.go:234: Found hardstate: {Term:2 Vote:1 Commit:4 XXX_unrecognized:[]}
2017/10/19 16:09:36 node.go:246: Group 0 found 4 entries
2017/10/19 16:09:36 raft.go:292: Restarting node for dgraphzero
2017/10/19 16:09:36 raft.go:567: INFO: 1 became follower at term 2
2017/10/19 16:09:36 raft.go:315: INFO: newRaft 1 [peers: [], term: 2, commit: 4, applied: 0, lastindex: 4, lastterm: 2]
Running Dgraph zero...
2017/10/19 16:09:36 open : no such file or directory
```

I can't find what is causing the error ***open : no such file or directory***, anyone experienced this? I'm using MacOS 10.12.3 (16D32) and installed dgraph version v0.8.3 using the command ***curl https://get.dgraph.io -sSf | bash***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug (update: it actually was confirmed as a bug and was [fixed](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/pull/1704)).
I've tried running it on Ubuntu and I've got the same error with `tls.on`.

Next I found the semi-manual test suite for tls [here](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/tree/master/contrib/tlstest).
Running it confirmed the error, tests required small adjustments (add `--memory_mb 2048`), but after that the same failure was reproduced.

To confirm it I also downloaded dgraph sources and checked what's going on under [delve debugger](https://github.com/derekparker/delve):

1) The config file is [parsed and parameters are saved into global vars](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/blob/master/cmd/dgraph/main.go#L139-L147)

2) TLS-related parameters [are used to create the tlsCfg](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/blob/master/cmd/dgraph/main.go#L438-L447)
  - Here we already can see the problem: not all the parameters are passed, for example, `tlsKey` and `tlsKeyPath` are missing

3) If we look deeper, into tls_helper.go, where the TLS actually configured, we can find that parameters from the config are
[passed into the `parseCertificate` method](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/blob/master/x/tls_helper.go#L187)

4) Here we use `config.Key` and `config.KeyPassphrase`, but they are empty

```
   182: func GenerateTLSConfig(config TLSHelperConfig) (tlsCfg *tls.Config, reloadConfig func(), err error) {
   183:         wrapper := new(wrapperTLSConfig)
   184:         tlsCfg = new(tls.Config)
   185:         wrapper.config = tlsCfg
   186:
=> 187:         cert, err := parseCertificate(config.CertRequired, config.Cert, config.Key, config.KeyPassphrase)
   188:         if err != nil {
   189:                 return nil, nil, err
   190:         }
   191:
   192:         if cert != nil {
(dlv) p config.CertRequired
true
(dlv) p config.Cert
"/home/seb/web/dgraph-test/test2.crt"
(dlv) p config.Key
""
(dlv) p config.KeyPassphrase
```

Then it fails inside the `parseCertificate` when it tries to read the file with certificate key.

I posted the [issue](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/issues/1691) on github.